# FreeIPA, limiting LDAP access for hosts

Tags: ldap, kerberos, openldap, freeipa

I'm orientating around FreeIPA. I have a test setup with a couple of hosts and am experimenting with LDAP. Once thing I noticed is that the hosts are able to query the entirety of the LDAP directory in FreeIPA:

```
kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab
ldapsearch -x
```

This will dump all users, groups, hosts and other items in the database. For a production environment, this is bad and could potentially expose this information on a host that has been compromised.

I'm having trouble finding a way to limit the access a host has to this information. How have others fixed this issue?

Comment: What is a point of a directory, if the content is not accessible?

Comment: FreeIPA is _by design_ a POSIX directory, with a list of managed hosts, a list of managed *nix users, a list of managed *nix groups, and access rules to define which user can access which hosts.If one host is compromised, then local queries on users & groups + queries on DNS will provide about the same amount of information.

Comment: For the record, I work for a large "systemic" bank, with a culture of paranoia, and IPA _(the supported RedHat version)_ is used for all *nix servers, espacially in Prod.

Comment: Well some content should be accessible, say all content in the hosts it's own hostgroup and all users having access to that hostgroup, e.g. only content that a host needs. 

However, having the entire directory available is a security risk and would allow a compromised machine to gain an fairly complete overview of the entire network. Don't you think?

Comment: Caveat: _multiple_ IPA directories are a good thing - for Prod, QA, etc (and 1 per DMZ)

Comment: So I work at an MSP with several separate environment. So instead of prod, qa etc, it would be Customer1, Customer2 etc.. Would it make sense to have separate directories for each of these?

Comment: Ah, yes, in case of multi-tenancy, you have to provide some kind of isolation. And FreeIPA has no feature for that AFAIK, so it means one instance per tenant. Plus, possibly, a separate instance just for bastion hosts (aka jump-off hosts) used by your Ops staff.

Comment: https://www.freeipa.org/page/V3/Multitenancy >> _"These are the changes necessary to the FreeIPA server to support a cloud deployment and multi-tenancy"_ >> ouch, it won't happen soon...